# How to find the lowest timing between two or more timings in a sorting algorithm in java?

Tags: java

I have a timing method that gets the amount of time it takes an algorithm to run.

```
public static long timing()
{
    long startTime, endTime,elapsedTime;

    startTime = System.nanoTime();
    endTime = System.nanoTime();
    elapsedTime = (endTime - startTime) ;

    return elapsedTime ;
}
```

**Assuming I had two sorting algorithms, an iterative merge sort call**

```
        int[] copy12 = new int[values.length];
        System.arraycopy(values,0,copy12,0,values.length);

        iterativeMergeSort(copy12);
        System.out.println("\nTime for iterative merge sort: " + timing() + " nanoseconds");
        isSorted(copy12);
        System.out.println("Iterative merge sort successfully sorted " + count + " elements");
```

**and an insertion sort call to value**

```
        int[] copy9 = new int[values.length];
        System.arraycopy(values,0,copy9,0,values.length);

        insertSort(copy9);
        System.out.println("\nTime for insertion sort: " + timing() + " nanoseconds");
        System.out.println("insertion sort successfully sorted " + count + " elements");
```

They both have different timings, I am trying to find the algorithm that runs the fastest and print it out like this:

```
The best sorting method is insertion sort 
It sorted all 1000 numbers in 656000 nanoseconds.
```

how is it possible in java that I can take these two different timings or if there are more algorithms and compare them to see which is faster? I've searched and i've not found a way of doing this.

Comment: I'm confused. If you can write this code, how can you not write the code that runs one and times it, then runs the other and times it, then reports on which was the fastest?

Comment: The method is called at different times for each statement. I can't seem to figure out how to compare their results @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments, it seems your question consists of two parts:

1. How to correctly compute the running time of a function;
2. How to find the smallest running time among 12 functions.

---

**1. Compute the running time of a function**

Your `timing()` method doesn't really do much.
What you really want to do is this:

```
long before = System.nanoTime();
someFunction();
long after = System.nanoTime();
System.out.println("Total elapsed time is " + (after-before) + " ns.");
```

This will get the total running time of the function `someFunction()` (for example, `insertSort()` in your case).
It is essentially storing two time stamps: one **before** the function call, and one **after** it.
The running time of the function will be the difference of the two.

This is how you can translate it to your problem:

```
// Time merge sort
long beforeMerge = System.nanoTime();
iterativeMergeSort(copy12);
long afterMerge = System.nanoTime();
long elapsedMerge = afterMerge - beforeMerge;

// Time insertion sort
long beforeInsert = System.nanoTime();
insertSort(copy9);
long afterInsert = System.nanoTime();
long elapsedInsert = afterInsert - beforeInsert;

// Print the elapsed time for each
System.out.println("Merge sort elapsed time = " + elapsedMerge + "ns.");
System.out.println("Insertion sort elapsed time = " + elapsedInsert + "ns.");
if(elapsedMerge<elapsedInsert)
    System.out.println("Merge sort was faster");
else
    System.out.println("Insertion sort was faster");
```

---

**2. Find the smallest running time among twelve functions**

Now that we can compute the running time of one function, we apply the same method on all twelve functions.
The idea is to store all the running times in an array, and then use a simple loop to determine which one was the fastest.

```
// This will contain the running times of the different sorting functions
long[] elapsed = new long[12];
// This will contain the names of the sorting functions
String[] names = new String[12];

long before, after; // used to compute the running times

// Time merge sort
before = System.nanoTime();
iterativeMergeSort(copy12);
after = System.nanoTime();
elapsed[0] = after-before;
names[0] = "Merge sort";

// Time insertion sort
before = System.nanoTime();
insertSort(copy9);
after = System.nanoTime();
elapsed[1] = after-before;
names[1] = "Insertion sort";

// ... Do the same for the others ...

// Determine the smallest running time
int fastest = 0;
for(int i=1; i<12; i++) {
    if(elapsed[i]<elapsed[fastest])
        fastest = i;
}
// Now the variable fastest contains the index of the fastest function
System.out.println("The fastest function was " + names[fastest] + ", with a running time of " + elapsed[fastest] + " nanoseconds.");
```

This will print something along the lines of:

```
The fastest function was Quicksort, with a running time of 12345 nanoseconds.
```

Comment: How do I find the lowest timing of the algorithms if I do this for two different sorting methods?

Comment: @T-- The code I added will print the running time of each sorting method.

Comment: How do you find the lowest timing among those timings that it will print to say with was faster?

Comment: @T-- Then you simply compare the two running times. I added an if-statement to do just that.

Comment: I have 12 sorting algorithms to compare , how would the if statement work?

Comment: @T-- I see. Your question seems to consist of two parts then (1. How to correctly get the running time of a function; 2. How to determine the smallest running time among twelve functions). It is generally better to split it into two separate questions, but I will give you an overview: you can store all the running times in an array and find the smallest one with a simple loop. I will add something to my answer.

Comment: you stored the numbers and got the smallest number in the array but How would it know the owner of that running time and print these along like `Quicksort was the fastest with 100 nanoseconds` stating the algorithm with the running time

Comment: @T-- Notice that each sorting function is represented by an index between 0 and 11. By knowing the index of the smallest running time, you know which function is the fastest. I used the array `names` to print the name of the fastest function: `names[i]` contains the name of the function whose running time was `elapsed[i]`. Thus if `elapsed[fastest]` is the smallest running time, then `names[fastest]` is the name of the fastest function.

Comment: @T-- Edited to print something similar to what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

well i think the easiest answer to your question is

```
Date date1;
Date date2;


 if((date1.compareTo(date2))<0)
     {
           System.out.println("date1 is the lowest date");
}         
else
{     
          System.out.println("date2 is the lowest date") ;         
}
```

compareTo function will return 1 if date1 is greate than date2 , 0 incase of equal and -1 if date1 is lessthan date2 .. this logic is to compare two make your own logic for more than two dates .. i am sure this will help you :)

Comment: if there are 12 algorithms to compare, this wouldn't solve it

Comment: try to put a loop for that 12 algorithms